# Chaining MapHierarchy() to add more Cases in EF code first

Tags: linq, entity-framework, code-first

I'm hoping there will be a crazy linq answer to this, it feels like there should be

Current code:

```
MapHierarchy().Case<Folder>(f => new { FolderId = f.Id, 
                                        f.Name,
                                        Type = 1 })
                      .Case<RootFolder>(f => new { f.RootName,
                                                    Type = 2 })
                      .ToTable("Folder");
```

Another method:

```
void AddAnotherFolder(something)
{
   something.Case<RootFolder>(f => new { f.RootName, Type = 2 })
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is pass that method into the MapHierarchy string - is that possible?

Something like...

```
MapHierarchy().Case<Folder>(f => new { FolderId = f.Id, 
                                        f.Name,
                                        Type = 1 })
                      .Case<RootFolder>(f => new { f.RootName,
                                                    Type = 2 })
                      .AddAnotherFolder(this)
                      .ToTable("Folder");
```

It feels like a linq question, would be VERY cool if it could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the method signature for `Case<T>`.  You should be able to create a similar extension method in a static class with where clauses for your particular types.  It might look something like this:

```
public static class ExtensionClass
{
    public static HierarchyEntityMap<TEntity> AddAnotherFolder<TEntity>(this HierarchyEntityMapGenerator<TEntity> source) where TEntity:RootFolder
    {
       return source.Case<TEntity>(f => new { f.RootName, Type = 2 });
    }
}
```

And to call it you'll just do `.AddAnotherFolder()` without the (this).

[NOT TESTED, BUT IT WILL BE SOMETHING LIKE THAT]